# Delete rows after last cell with data in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I want to figure out a code to delete all the rows after the last row of my copied data in column "C".

So let's say my data in column C ends at row 1265, the code is suppose to delete all the rows after that..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim LastRowColC As Long, LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastRowColC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow > LastRowColC Then
    Rows(LastRowColC + 1 & ":" & LastRow).Delete
    'OR
    'Rows(LastRowColC + 1 & ":" & LastRow).Clear
End If
End Sub
```

If the data is in an Excel Table, try it like this...

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim LastRowColC As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
LastRow = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastRowColC = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(3).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
If LastRow > LastRowColC Then
    Rows(LastRowColC + 1 & ":" & LastRow).Delete
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this looks great. But it doesn't work in the sheet I need it to work in... I think the problem might be that its a table? Its called 'tabel1'

It does however work as a charm when I cope it over to a new sheet as values. 

Would I be able to make it work in a sheet with a table?

Comment: Okay. Added another solution which will work in the case if the data is in an Excel Table.